# How to change UIRoot scale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I'm using Unity3D with C#. Also, I'm using nGUI 2.7.0 for UI.

When I create new UI my UI Root (2D)'s scaling is like 0.005633803 on all axis.
I can't change it's scaling in inspector. How do I do that?

The problem is, it's children, menu items, are scaled to even smallest value. So when I use something like PopupMenu, subitems are scaled to 1, and are not visible.

Comment: Hi guy. I got the same problem. Have you reach any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, update to the latest NGUI. 3.x.x changes quite a lot and makes it a much more powerful tool.

The scale of you UIRoot is based off of the resolution you set it too. All the children SHOULD have a scale of (1, 1, 1).